# Entity Framework SQLite Foreign Keys works on saving but not reading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a xamarin application with EF Core 2.0.1 and am having an odd issue with foreign keys not behaving properly in my SQLite database.

It appears that foreign keys works on saving but when i recover the entity the foreign key property will always be null. I've inspected the SQLLIte db file and it has a foreign key constraint on the table and the PRAGMA is enabled.

What am i doing wrong here?

**My Model with key**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The id of the form template
    /// </summary>
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Link to the template
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("TemplateId")]
    public virtual FormTemplate FormTemplate { get; set; }
```

**The mapped model**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifier for the form template.
    /// This comes from the API.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

**My data context initializer**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DatabaseContext(string databaseFilePath)
    {
        DatabaseFilePath = databaseFilePath;
        Database.EnsureCreated(); // Use this in testing so that we don't have to make migrations on every db change
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={DatabaseFilePath}");
    }
```

**here is the SQL schema created when viewing the db**

```
CREATE TABLE `FormsMessages` (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `TemplateId`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_FormsMessages_FormTemplates_TemplateId` FOREIGN KEY(`TemplateId`) REFERENCES `FormTemplates`(`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[image: pragma sql db]

It appears the SQL BD has the constraint from the EF model. Yet when i try to go through the navigation property the `FormTemplate` is always `null` even if i save it with `FormTemplate = myinstance`. (BTW the database explorer shows the templateId gets populated when i do this.)

Comment: It's `null` because most likely you didn't request EF Core to load it. See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation.

Comment: Nope. This is how it is resolved. `ctx.FormsMessages.Include(x => x.FormTemplate).`

Comment: please add it as an answer `ctx.FormsMessages.Include(x => x.FormTemplate)` solved my problem too